# Is there a way to make a list of a list then remove the first item in that list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to sort some sales data, but the data is collected per "bill", and I want to look at the items in each bill.

I have tried to split the columns to get a list of the items, but they won't behave as I want. I have tried to iterate through, but all I do is removing the first item per row.

```
frame = {'Items': ["1 Nail, 2 Cups", "3 Nail, 1 Cups", "1 Hammer, 3 Cups"],
        'Date': ['03-2019','03-2019','03-2019']}

df = pd.DataFrame(frame)

df['Items split'] = df['Items'].str.split(",")

df.head()
```

```
Items   Date    Items split
0   1 Nail, 2 Cups  03-2019 [1 Nail, 2 Cups]
1   3 Nail, 1 Cups  03-2019 [3 Nail, 1 Cups]
2   1 Hammer, 3 Cups    03-2019 [1 Hammer, 3 Cups]
```

```
for item in df['Items split']:
    for i in item:
        print (i)
```

```
1 Nail
 2 Cups
3 Nail
 1 Cups
1 Hammer
 3 Cups
```

I want to be able to find correlations between items per bill.
E.g. How often does Nail and Cups go together?

But to do this I imagine I need to remove the number infront, as each it reads 1 Nail and 3 Nails as different.

It would also be interesting to be able to e.g. multiply with the number in another column. So I can do a count of each item to get a total.

Clarification on the last part:
Let's say we have 2 Nails, 3 Iron Cups, 1 Straw in one field. By splitting the bill and removing the numbers I'm able to now find correlations between items, but I can't see how many items we actually sold. If possible I'm thinking a solution would be to split out the integer in front, multiply it with the item name. Then it would look something like Nails,Nails,Iron Cups,Iron Cups,Iron Cups,Straw. Then I can count number of times Nails appear etc.

Comment: For the "multiply with the number in another column" thing you should be more concrete.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in Detail

```
for item in df['Items split']:    
    for i in item:
        i = i.lstrip() #remove leading whitespaces
        arr = i.split(' ') #split string at whitespaces --> transforms '1 nail' into ['1','nail'] 
        arr = arr[1:] #remove the first element (the 1 of ['1', 'nail'])
        final_string = ' '.join(arr) #joins the array to a string seperated by whitespaces. So the Program also works for Materials with spaces like "100 Long Nail"
        print(final_string)
```

Same solution as a oneliner:

```
for item in df['Items split']:    
    for i in item:
        print(' '.join(i.lstrip().split(' ')[1:]))
```

Output for both examples:

```
Nail
Cups
Nail
Cups
Hammer
Cups
```

**Edit:**

For the counting you mentioned you can just cast the first element of the item array to int like that:

```
for items in df['Items split']:    
    for item in items:
        item_array = item.lstrip().split(' ')
        for i in range(int(item_array[0])):
            print(' '.join(item_array[1:]))
```

Output:

```
Nail
Cups
Cups
Nail
Nail
Nail
Cups
Hammer
Cups
Cups
Cups
```